# ADC EVAL_AD7984_PMDZ voltage source and signal source sharing common ground

Tags: adc, ground, voltage-source

EDIT: (problem definition shortened into 2 sentences)

For anyone using EVAL_AD7984_PMDZ and having troubles to apply -2.5, 0, 7.5 [V] and signal to differential probes, because the voltage source and signal source shares ground (then there is 2.5 [V] difference between the two), check the last comment for solution.

ORIGINAL POST:

I got differential [ADC EVAL_AD7984_PMDZ](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7984.pdf) (page 17 connection) on ZedBoard working just fine (from -5 to 5 [V]). It requires not only 3.3 [V] from PMOD connection (logic) but also -2.5, 0, 7.5 [V] from external power source (Laboratory DC Power Supply - 2 adjustable outputs, that I have connected in series, thus I have "ground" on the middle pin, while on the other 2 pins there is -2.5 and 7.5 - relative to my "ground").

And here it comes, when I introduce input from **another** Laboratory DC Power Supply, the readings are fine within whole range.

But when I introduce signal from *AFG-2125 Arbitrary Function Generator*, there is offset of 2.5 [V] from both of the ADC input pins and it kind of messes up whole measurement that is below 2.5 [V].

May I get a little bit of insight on that ?

---

The ground of the ADC probes is the "ground" mentioned above.

Technically I have 3 grounds:

- ZedBoard (and thus PMOD connection)(powered from its own power source)
- External power source for the ADC (with the "ground")
- Signal Generator ground

I am not sure how to resolve that. Would it help if the Signal Generator was battery powered ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGbyNk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(I am sorry if some electrical engineer finds the above schematic offensive)

---

Schematics for EVAL_AD7984_PMDZ

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're doing.  You can add circuit diagrams to your post (click the 7th icon from the left, which looks like a pencil and a circuit). That would make it clearer what was connected to what.
Also, as a courtesy to the people who are trying to help, you could provide datasheets for the [ADC](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7984.pdf), [eval board](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/UG-340.pdf) and other bits of kit.

Comment: Is your lab supply grounded to mains earth ground? Sounds like both the signal generator and lab supply might have the same ground (the signal generator is single ended, so connecting it to a diff ADC is not so great).

Comment: Yeah, from my understanding and measurements, the Power Source and Signal Generator share the same ground, but that seems like a crappy Signal Generator then. Also, why is the differential ADC not so great? I would say it is advantage to have two probes independent of ground and measure the difference between them (not probe and ground).

Comment: Check the jumper configuration.  The board can be configured for differential or single ended mode, jumper SL10 should be in position A.
Do you have a 'scope?

Comment: I am not sure whether we are talking about the same product, the board I have doesn't contain any jumpers, just simple PMOD (12 pins) and 2 probe connections (small round golden connectors) ... yes, I do have a scope

Comment: oops, my bad, I was looking at the eval board I linked in my first comment, which seems to be the wrong one.  The first eval board schematic you posted does have an equivalent jumper in it though, labelled SL1. Looking at the photo, it might be a surface mount one, close to the three way terminal block.  It needs to be in positon A, but in the photo it's in position B.

Comment: CHECKED, it is in position A on my board

Comment: Oh well, so much for that. Time to get the scope out then.  Connect the ground clip to whichever terminal of your power supply is at mains ground (I'm still not quite clear on that - you could add that to your schematic) and probe around for the signals. Look at both the amplitude of the signal from the AFG and at the DC offset.  You should be able to follow the inputs from the SMB connectors to pin 3, then pin 6 of the buffers right through to pins 3 and 4 of the ADC, without any changes to amplitude or offset.

Comment: thank you for valuable opinion, but I cant help to say that the ADC seems to work fine (testing with DC Power Supply instead of AFG worked as expected) ... the problem, as you have implied above, is the ground ... which one is the right one and WHY is the groud of AFG different from DC Power Supply ?

Comment: I was hoping to work out which part of the board was mangling the signals.  Could be the buffers or the ADC. I'm still not clear where the grounds are in your circuit.  Provided that neither "ground" nor "V+" from the AFG go below the ground or above the 7.5V supply on your eval board it ought to work.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood what you are doing.  Which output from the lab power supply is connected to mains ground?

Comment: Hmm, you are right .... I might have done mistake that I have just realized .... I will try to power the ADC from battery to make it "ground" independent and then apply signal from AFG ... (does it make sense ?)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by mains ground ? I got both outputs of DC Power Supply (generating signal to test ADC) connected to ADC probes ... the ADC ground is not connected, because there is this 2.5 [V] off-set

Comment: I was referring to the power supply you have connected to the -2.5V/GND/+7.5V terminals on the eval board.  Re-reading your question I think you might be supplying mains ground/+2.5/+10 to those terminals? If so, see my answer below.

Comment: Actually, i am applying ground/+2.5/+10 and I have chosen the 2.5 [V] to be my "ground" (2.5 [V] over the DC supply ground so I would have required -2.5 [V] - ADC requires that) .... so I have chosen my "ground" for the ADC converter to be 2.5 [V] making it floating 2.5 [V] over ground of AFG ... BUT I counted on differential probes to counter this "floating" ... well, because they are differential

Comment: OK, I now understand what you are doing.  My answer below explains why this is not working, and I've updated it a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eval board consists of a unity gain buffer on each input, the output of which goes into the ADC.  Barring some details about current and input impedance, it is as though the board inputs are connected to the ADC inputs.  For the ADC to work, the input voltages need to be between the ADC's ground pin and the ADC's vref pin (see datasheet table 2 -> ANALOG INPUT -> Voltage Range).

If you are powering it from a DC power supply with the eval board's -2.5V input at mains ground, then the eval board ground and hence the ADC's ground pin are at mains ground +2.5V. The ADC's vref pin is held at eval board ground + 5V by the voltage reference IC.

So when either input drops below mains + 2.5V, the corresponding ADC input drops below ADC ground.  That takes the ADC out of spec, so you can't expect it to work properly. Worse, it goes below ADC ground pin -0.3V, which is outside the absolute maximum rating for the chip (datasheet page 6) which could damage the chip. Fortunately, the board includes some 22 ohm resistors which will limit the current and probably protect the ADC from damage.

You seem to be expecting the fact that the amplifier is differential to mean it can take any differential input. That's not the case. Differential means the output of the ADC is the difference between the inputs, but for the ADC to work the inputs need to be within the input limits. Every ADC and differential amplifier has input limits - you wouldn't expect to connect 1000000V to one input and 1000001V to the other and read one volt without fireworks. For this ADC, the limits are ground to Vref (which is 5V on the eval board). Very few differential amps or ADCs accept input voltages outside their power supply voltage range. If you really need that, then you need to look at either an isolating amplifier or a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish this thread with short answer. Powering the EVAL_AD7984_PMDZ requires the PMOD connection 3.3[V] and GND (pins 5, 6 and 11, 12 on any 12 pin PMOD header) and -2.5, 0, +7,5 [V] on J3 connector. To prevent the above described problems (shared ground between source and signal generator) provide the voltages (-2.5, 0, +7,5 [V]) from a battery source, OR use Voltage Inverter to obtain -2.5 [V] (thus, the shared grounds are at the same level). The LT1054 Voltage Inverter is easy to use and does the job very well.

http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1054lfh.pdf page 10